# C++/CLI callback to C#

Tags: c#, c++, command-line-interface, wrapper

I have a C library (DLL) where I have callback functions with defined datatypes.

Now I am writing Wrapper(DLL) for this in C++/CLI. This Wrapper Dll will be used in my C# application.

How to Implement the callback in C++/CLI so that i can write the call back function in C# an passt it through the wrapper to the C librarby.

Dll Libray ...

```
# C libary (DLL) *.h file
...
typedef void (*TOnMonitoringStateCB)(const ROBOT_STATE);
typedef void (*TOnMonitoringDataCB)(const LPMONITORING_DATA);
...
DRFL_API void _SetOnMonitoringState(LPROBOTCONTROL pCtrl, TOnMonitoringStateCB pCallbackFunc);
DRFL_API void _SetOnMonitoringData(LPROBOTCONTROL pCtrl, TOnMonitoringDataCB pCallbackFunc); 
...
class CDRFL
{
public:
    // robot status data
    void SetOnMonitoringState(TOnMonitoringStateCB pCallbackFunc) { _SetOnMonitoringState(_rbtCtrl, pCallbackFunc); };
    // robot operating data
    void SetOnMonitoringData(TOnMonitoringDataCB pCallbackFunc) { _SetOnMonitoringData(_rbtCtrl, pCallbackFunc); };
...
```

Wrapper (DLL) C++/CLI ...

```
# C++/CLI *.h (my try)
...
public delegate void ManagedTOnMonitoringStateCB(const RobotState);
public delegate void ManagedTOnMonitoringDataCB(const LpMonitoringDate);
...
public ref class WrapperClass
{
   ...
   void SetOnMonitoringState(ManagedTOnMonitoringStateCB^ callbackFunc);
   void SetOnMonitoringData(ManagedTOnMonitoringDataCB^ callbackFunc);
   ...
}
# *.cpp (my try)
...
void WrapperClass::SetOnMonitoringState(ManagedTOnMonitoringStateCB^ callbackFunc)
{
    IntPtr cbPtr = System::Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal::GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(callbackFunc);
    _rbtCtrl->SetOnMonitoringState(static_cast<CLibrarbyc::TOnMonitoringStateCB>(cbPtr.ToPointer()));
};
void WrapperClass::SetOnMonitoringData(ManagedTOnMonitoringDataCB^ callbackFunc)
{
    IntPtr cbPtr = System::Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal::GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(callbackFunc);
    _rbtCtrl->SetOnMonitoringData(static_cast<CLibrarbyc::TOnMonitoringDataCB>(cbPtr.ToPointer()));
};
...
```

C# ...

```
...
_rbtCtrl.SetOnMonitoringState(OnMonitoringState());

 void OnMonitoringState()
 {
     textBox1.AppendText("...");
 }

_rbtCtrl.SetOnMonitoringData(OnMonitoringData());

 void OnMonitoringData()
 {
     textBox1.AppendText("...");
 }
...
```

The C++/CLI seems to be OK, but in the C# part I always have problems with the Converting the types.
It also can be a problem of the initialisaten of the callbackfunction and the handling of the function in C#.
But maybe there is also and erro in the C++/CLI Wrapper or it can be done easier, but it compiles.

Comment: C++/CLI ≠ C++.  Different languages.  Like how Objective-C++ is a different language from C++.  The question should not have the `c++` tag.

Comment: The C# methods are not correct, they need a parameter to match the delegate type.  So `void OnMonitoringData(MonitoringData data)` for example.  Where MonitoringData is a wrapper for the MONITORING_DATA native type.  How this went wrong is hard to guess since the code snippets don't show these C++/CLI wrapper type declarations.  Another requirement is that the delegate objects need to be stored so the garbage collector won't release them.